# Quality Center Filters and Favorites Action

Tags: hp-quality-center

I am trying to change the filters in the display of the current user in the Defects module.

I have set the "tdc.BUGFactory.Filter" object with my filter and i can access the data, but i cannot force it to be displayed to the user! any idea on how to do that?

If i use a SQL command to store it in the common settings table, would it be possible to call an action to load the "Favorites" view i created to the user?

Thanks,
Achraf

================================================================

I found the answer, however stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post it:

I fonud the answer through SQA Forums, to force a filter you use the following

```
Set defectFilter = tDConenction.BugFactory.Filter ' Example to set a filter criteria
defectFilter.Field ("BG_DETECION_DATE") = "[Today]" 
SetDefectsFilter defectFilter.Text 
Set defectFilter = Nothing
```

There is also a function called GetDefectsFilter() which gets the current filter